# Openstack - mix pinned and unpinned VMs on the same host

Tags: openstack

Is it possible in Openstack to have 2 VMs instantiated on the same host, where:

- VM1 is instantiated from the "unpinned" `2-vCPU flavor (hw:cpu_policy not set)`
- VM2 is instantiated from the "pinned" `2-vCPU flavor (hw:cpu_policy=dedicated)`

and be sure that VM2's pinned vCPUs (thus physical CPUs) will not be used by VM1?

When reading the 'CPU topologies' section in the OpenStack docs it says:

> Caution: Host aggregates should be used to separate pinned instances
>   from unpinned instances as the latter will not respect the resourcing
>   requirements of the former.

so according to above it looks it's not possible. Would like to confirm that.

Cause if you can't mix pinned and unpinned VMs on 1 host it seems to me like a huge limitation, isn't it? Asking in the telecom context where pinning is often a must for some VMs (VNFCs) and for the others not; and sometimes it's desirable to have them on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Nova does not support mixed pinned/unpinned on a single VM (at least not out of the box), but it is a feature they are looking at implementing.

You can read about the current suggested implementation [here](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/545734/10/specs/rocky/approved/mixed-cpu-policy-instance.rst).

Additional reading on work related to this blueprint is available [here](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/555081/16/specs/stein/approved/cpu-resources.rst).

Comment: Thanks very much for really interesting material you gave in the links.However, I think I have asked about slightly different setup - I asked about running **2 VM instances**, one pinned the other unpinned, **on the same host**. All this in relation to comment from Openstack docs: "Caution: Host aggregates should be used to separate pinned instances from unpinned instances as the latter will not respect the resourcing requirements of the former.".